# Copy existing Object

Tags: javascript

I am a little confused.

Basically, framerjs exports my photoshop document into a HTML5 website. All of the elements seem to be in a PSD object. I can adress each item of my document by PSD["Name of the Element"]. Framer calls these "Views". so it is possible to create a new view by myNewView = new View(); A View can contain text, image, etc. So far, so good.

I am trying the following: from each existing view, I want to create a new view which displays the name of the original view. The new views should be individually adressable.

```
var ypsilon = 30;

// go through all Elements in PSD
for (var layerGroupName in PSD) {
var newView = PSD[layerGroupName].name + "_new";
var newViewName = PSD[layerGroupName].name + "_new";

//create the new view
newView = new ImageView({x:20, y:ypsilon, width:400, height:30});

// name the new view
newView.name = newViewName;

// style for the new view
newView.style = {
            "font-family": "Arial",
            "font-size": "18px",
            "font-weight": "bold",
            "text-align": "left",
            "color": "white"
            }
// show the new view
newView.html = newViewName;

// position the next view y+30px
ypsilon = ypsilon + 30;
```

}

This is what I have and I know why it is wrong. I can see all the new views but I cannot adress them by their name. I only can adress "newView". I know that the `for` loop is wrong in this case and so I overwrite newView all the time instead of getting something like "layerGroupName_new". I haven't managed to work with `.lenght` which was my idea of working with a `for` loop. So I am stuck at the moment and would be very glad if some of you nice people could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to access the views directly by name, you could put them all on an array and iterate over them. An alternative would be to store them on an object using the name as the key which will allow you to access them specifically by name.

Demonstration of both approaches:

```
var ypsilon = 30;

// Using an array
var views = [];

// Using an object
var viewDictionary = {};

// go through all Elements in PSD
for (var layerGroupName in PSD) {
    var newView = PSD[layerGroupName].name + "_new";
    var newViewName = PSD[layerGroupName].name + "_new";

    //create the new view
    newView = new ImageView({x:20, y:ypsilon, width:400, height:30});

    // name the new view
    newView.name = newViewName;

    // style for the new view
    newView.style = {
                "font-family": "Arial",
                "font-size": "18px",
                "font-weight": "bold",
                "text-align": "left",
                "color": "white"
                }
    // show the new view
    newView.html = newViewName;

    // position the next view y+30px
    ypsilon = ypsilon + 30;

    views.push(newView);

    viewDictionary[newViewName] = newView;
}

// Looping over all the views and acting on them
for (var i = 0, view; i < views.length; i ++) {
    view = views[i];
    // do stuff with view
}

// Accessing a specific view by name via the viewDictionary
var view = viewDictionary['myViewName_new'];
```

Comment: this is brilliant. i understand the version with the array. so now i can do views[0].on("click", function(event) {
 views[0].x = 100
 }) what is wonderful. just as i am curious: how would this work with viewDictionary object. this would be nice to adress by name. so for example a original view is called "Background" the new is "Background_new". viewDictionary['Background_new'].x = 100 gives me an error. would you be so nice to clear things up for me (or do i talk total nonsense)?

Comment: You don't talk nonsense :) The way you're trying to access the dictionary is correct. Double check you're adding the view to the object using the same key you're using to access it.